# Python Help - Perform "isnumber(search" in Python

Tags: python, excel-formula

I've been searching high and low for this answer and I can't find a suitable solution anywhere.

I want to review and categorise a set of keywords in a column, I normally do this with a "isnumber(search" but I'm limited to 64 variants. An example of the code I use can be found below:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("bag",A2)),"Bags",
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("rucksack",A2)),"Bags",
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("handbag",A2)),"Bags",
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("purse",A2)),"Personal Bags",
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("wallet",A2)),"Personal Bags")))))
```

The expected output would be as below:

| Keyword | Category |
| --- | --- |
| handbag | Bags |
| rucksack | Bags |
| drawstring bags | Bags |
| tote bag | Bags |
| cotton tote | FALSE |
| purse | Personal Bags |
| wallet | Personal Bags |

Can the same functionality be replicated in Python?

I want the layout to be column A <- Keywords, column B <- Category.

I have seen a variant of this but the it used a "true" or "false" statement and added endless columns to the right of the "keyword" column, but its labour intensive to clean up.

If anyone knows how to replicate the Excel formula in Python it would be greatly appreciated :)

Cheers

Comment: You should provide an example of your data and the expected output

Comment: No worries, added output data :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to search sets of items to see which set any particular item falls into?

```
def categoriseItems(currVar):
    bags = set(["handbag", "rucksack", "drawstring bags", "tote bag"])
    personalBags = set(["purse", "wallet"])

    itemCat = None
    if currVar in bags:
        itemCat = "bags"
    elif currVar in personalBags:
        itemCat = "personal bags"

    if not itemCat:
        print("Item " + currVar + " not categorised")

    return [currVar, itemCat]
```

edit:

Then, if you want your output in that format, is it openpyxl?

If so, assemble data into a list like:

```
rows = [
       ["Keyword",  "Category"],
       ]
```

Then, with the stuff I had above as either an in-line for loop for each item or as a separate function called for each item (re-arranged so separate function):

```
currVar = A2.text   #If your lifting this from a spreadsheet, openpyxl is prob your goto library - this line is just pseudocode
```

Below assumes you've a list of text entries corresponding to items you want processed:

```
for currVar in listOfVars:
    rows.append(categoriseItem(currVar))



def writeToWB(rows):
    import openpyxl
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    ws = wb.active

    for row in rows:
        ws.append(row)

    wb.save("myWorkbook.xlsx")
```

Sorry, bit disjointed - I'm rushing!

Comment: Thanks guys for the responses, I'm quiet new to Python, which libraries would I need to run the above?

Comment: Regarding openpyxl, if I can import the data into a data frame, then run the keyword mapping code, then review the results so I can check its worked. The next step would be to export the file

Comment: Yeah - and if your gonna import into a dataframe, I'd advise you try to use a vector op to do the work [work all the column in one go]. While it'll make no difference here, it'll be far quicker for any heavy tasks you do in future and its better to learn sooner rather than later

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to do bucket-sort/binning/categorizing of your data you can use a python dict to do your mapping:

```
keyword = A2.text
mapping = {'handbag': 'Bags', 'rucksack': 'Bags', 'cotton tote': false}
try:
    result = mapping[keyword]
except KeyError:
    print("Keyword not found")

ws['B2'] = result
```

This can also be combined with Amiga500's answer if you want to avoid the if-chain.

Comment: Hi Flo, Thanks for replying, does the above code place the mapping result in the adjacent column? So the results would appear in column "B"?

Comment: This is only the core mapping. You will have to put the result into your corresponding excel api place/cell whatever. 
I don't know what kind of excel package you use in python.

Comment: I'm using openpyxl, i'm guessing this is a fairly common package

Comment: Ok added assignment from openpyxl docs. Please note this is more or less a pseudocode example. You need to formulate some sort of iteration over your input cells which hand the cell data to the mapping code.

Comment: Ah right, as I say i'm fairly new to Python, do you know how to map the results to the corresponding column?

Comment: it's the line `ws['B2'] = result`. Please consult the openpyxl docs for further details.